Power Apps Form Control: Form says it submitted successfully, but does not show up on SharePoint List?
I'm pretty new to Power Apps. I've been working on an app for my organization to track employee information, leave, and appointments, tying into SharePoint Lists in a neater way. I had everything working pretty well with Patch, but ran into trouble when I needed to include attachments for our leave tracking List. When combining Submit Form (just for the attachments) and my existing (otherwise working) Patch function, I was unable to get it to work, so I built a form control from the data source.
However, when I submit the form (whether for a new item or to modify an existing one), the app thinks the submission was successful, but no changes appear on the List. It appears to function exactly as intended while using it, right up until I hit submit and it thinks it works but... doesn't.
I'm attaching pictures of the two screens in use, and I'll lay out the modifications I've made to the form. (Note that a completely unmodified form does work, so I assume one of my modifications has junked it.)


Modifications:

I made three of the fields hidden (Visible: false), and for two of these I modified the default value of the input field within the data card, something like below. One automatically enters the correct Person column record based on Screen 1. When I make the field visible, it looks right. The other calculates the title based on type of leave and member name, which again looks right when I make the field visible.
If(Not isNew, Parent.Default, LookUp(Roster,ID=ListID).'Member Profile')
If(Not isNew, Parent.Default, Leave_Loc_Data.Selected.Value&" - "&LookUp(Roster,ID=ListID).Title)

I modified the border or FalseFill value of a couple fields to help them stand out when they're not filled out as required. Example below.
If(Leave_Loc_Data.Selected.Value<>"Local" And Start_Data.SelectedDate < varWeek,Color.Red,If(IsBlank(Parent.Error), Parent.BorderColor, Color.Red))

I adjusted the Required field on a few items, example:
If(IMR_Status_Data.Selected.Value <> "Green",true,false)

I added two custom data cards that are not linked to fields on the SharePoint List, but rather used in validation/to formulate the hidden item title. One of these has a variable Required field:
If(Start_Data.SelectedDate < varNextDay,true,false)


The DisplayMode field for the button that submits the form also serves as data validation, only enabled if the fields are filled out as required:
If(ListID <> 0 And varInvis And Reason_Data.Text<>"" And Leave_Loc_Data.Selected.Value<>"" And (Overseas_Data.Value Or Loc_Stat_Data.Selected.Value<>"OCONUS") And Start_Data.SelectedDate <= End_Data.SelectedDate And (Day_Notice_Data.Value Or Start_Data.SelectedDate >= varNextDay) And (CountRows(Attachments_Data.Attachments) > 0 Or (Start_Data.SelectedDate >= varWeek Or Leave_Loc_Data.Selected.Value="Local")) And Leave_Dest_Data.Text<>"" And Mode_Data.Selected.Value<>"" And IMR_Status_Data.Selected.Value<>"" And (IMR_Alibi_Data.Text<>"" Or IMR_Status_Data.Selected.Value="Green") And Agree1_Data.Value And Agree2_Data.Value,DisplayMode.Edit,DisplayMode.Disabled)

varNextDay and varWeek are just today plus a number of days. Again, this part of the form is functioning as expected. And, just to be thorough, here's the OnSelect code for the button that submits the form:
SubmitForm(Form1); Set(varInvis,false); ResetForm(Form1); UpdateContext({PatchTimer: true})
The PatchTimer onTimerEnd (used mostly as a visual cue to the user that the form was submitted and to set it up for a new submission if desired):
UpdateContext({PatchTimer: false}); Set(varInvis, true); Set(isNew, true); Set(LeaveID,0); NewForm(Form1)
That's really about it. I'm happy to share more information if anything could be helpful. I can't figure out what could possibly be causing the form to behave as if it's working when it's not. If anyone has insight, I really appreciate it. Thank you!
